# Added escaped quotes to JSON in Flask app with mongoDB

Tags: python, json, mongodb, flask

I am trying to create API for my Flask project. I have data stored in     mongoDB and for building API I am using flask_restful. The problem is that in JSON are added escaped quotes and I cannot figure why and I rather have my JSON without them.

This is how my get function looks like:

```
from flask_restful import Resource
import json
from bson import json_util

class Harvests(Resource):

    def get(self):
        json_docs = []

        for doc in db.collection.find():
            json_doc = json.dumps(doc, default=json_util.default)
            json_docs.append(json_doc)

        return json_docs
```

In app.py it is just like that

```
api = Api(app)
api.add_resource(Harvests, '/api/harvests')
```

And I get JSON with escaped quotes (in browser or with curl)

```
[
"{\"_id\": {\"$oid\": \"5c05429cc4247917d66163a7\"},...
]
```

If I try this outside Flask (print JSON from mongo) and it works just fine. I tried use .replace(), but I think is not most elegant solution, but it did not work anyway. Any idea how I should get rid off these backslashes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see is absolutely what you should expect to see according to your code, so I think there is a misunderstanding at some point.  Let me explain what you are doing.

You convert each doc (a data structure) into a jsonified version (a string) of this data.  Then you gather these strings in a list.  Later you see this list, and of course you see a list of strings.  Each of these strings contains a jsonified version of a data structure (a dictionary with opening braces, keys and values inside, and each key is a string itself with quotes, so these quotes are escaped within the jsonified string).

I recommend to collect your documents into a `list` and then convert that `list` to json instead:

```
def get(self):
    docs = []

    for doc in db.collection.find():
        docs.append(doc)

    return json.dumps(docs, default=json_util.default)
```

This way you get one json string representing the list of docs.

Maybe your framework is already applying a jsonifying automatically, in this case just don't do this step yourself:

```
    return docs
```

Just use this instead.

Comment: Thank you very much! It really helps me find a solution. If I return only docs,, then I get TypeError: Object of type ObjectId is not JSON serializable. If I return only json.dumps than result is same as before, but if I use json.loads(json.dumps(docs, default=json_util.default)) than it works fine.

Comment: Oh, then you have something which isn't serializable normally, but with `default=json_util.default` it is.  Can't you make your data structures simpler so that they do not contains weird stuff?  This encoding–decoding step is not the optimal way of course.

Comment: I don't design the data structure and unfortunately I can't change it. I know it isn't optimal, but I hope it do the job. I have tried dumps() from bson.json_util too but still same result.

Comment: Yeah, sometimes we have to live with poorly designed frameworks/APIs/etc. and find a more or less ugly workaround to achieve our goals …  But in your case I propose to have a look at http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/119/ as it seems to deal with your problem.